# Collaborator changes do not update in R package but github

Tags: function, github, package, rstudio, collaboration

I am currently working on developing a few functions for a R package together with a collaborator (who set up the package initially).

However, when I edit his functions in my RStudio, commit and push them, they do appear on the github but not in the package version when I download it again/ the functions still have old mistakes in that I had fixed for example.

Anyone any ideas what is going on?

Tried restarting and re -installing.

Comment: How are you installing the package after uploading new code? `remotes::install_github()` or `install.packages()`? Or are you pulling with git? Does the github repository have more than one branch and are you pushing to the correct branch?